# How to show gratitude to all the people who posted great answers to my question?

Tags: discussion, answers, thanks

I have posted a [question about the Romans in London (UK)](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/49073/what-roman-legions-were-present-in-london-uk) and I liked all the comments and specially `both` answers that were given to my question.

Both answers were very good, I just chose the one I did on the grounds of the links provided were more to my liking but I appreciated both of them answers and both are correct too, `basically there were no legions stationed in London, but a fort was there`.

I wanted to show my gratitude to the people who wrote those answers, other than upvoting those answers, is there anything would be proper(`according to the rules of the site`) to do?

Comment: You're probably looking for this because not much else comes to mind: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)